# Track visitors through an Iframe google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to use google analytics to record data from visitors viewing through an iframe?

I added the ID tags to every page on my site. The site is mainly accesed through an iframe. The number of visitors on my google analytics only showed a few, but I know for a fact lots more people are using iframes to see the site.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in this regard require access to the iframe page, and are the following:

- insert the tracking directly in the iframe (via GTM or Analytics code);
- pass the interaction information (i.e. click on a button) from the iframe to the *parent* page and send it to Analytics from the page hosting the iframe.

Therefore, the support of developers accessing the site in the iframe is required.